# asp.net application loses menu on ipad

Tags: asp.net, ipad, testing

Working on a website http://www.ArenaText.com written in asp.net with Microsoft AJAX control toolkit.  iPad users are saying that the menu at the top of the page (master form) initially displays and then as soon as they click on a page in the menu - the menu disapears.

I dont have an iPad to test with.  I tried some ipad simulators (on line) and they are not showing the problem.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the issue on Google Chrome + Windows 7, too.

I can tell you that the menu is being rendered (you can actually see the markup if you click View Source) but this class is making it disappear.

```
.ctl00_Menu1_0 {
background-color: white;
visibility: hidden;
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
```

On Chrome, I can disable some elements of the class (using the Developer Tool) and the menu displays again.

Apparently, `position`, `display` and `visibility` setting in that CSS class are the culprits.

Note: Explorer 9 on Windows 7 does not have the same issue, the menu always displays properly.

I Hope this is helpful.